# merge secondary database into main one avoiding duplicate

Tags: sqlite

I have two databases with the same structure. The first is the main one, while the second get updated periodically (in reality I have multiple "secondary" databases that I want to merge one by one into the main one).

The structure of the main and the secondary databases is identical.

I want to periodically dump all **new** values from the secondary database in the main one. However, the second time I do it, I want to exclude rows that were already copied the first time (and so on).

The tables in all these database have:

- an `ID` column set as `PRIMARY KEY` going from 1 to N **for each database** (I suspect this was a mistake, but at the moment I can't change this)
- a `DATE` column, representing a posix timestamp (float)
- some other columns

My code looks like this:

```
ATTACH DATABASE secondary.db AS temp_db
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table_temp
CREATE TABLE my_table_temp AS SELECT * FROM my_table
INSERT INTO main.my_table_temp  SELECT * FROM temp_db.my_table
DELETE FROM my_table
INSERT INTO main.my_table SELECT DISTINCT * FROM main.my_table_temp ORDER BY date
DROP TABLE my_table_temp
```

the problem is that - I suspect due to the repeated `ID` column - the `DISTINCT` clause returns me:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: my_table.id
```

However I don't care **at all** of the `ID` field that could also be dropped or reset.

NOTES:

- the secondary databases are constantly updated by a code that - at the moment - I can't change
- I initialize the "main" database copy-pasting one of the secondary to avoid regenerating the whole structure from scratch. Maybe there is a better way of doing this

Apologies if this is a naive question, but I'm very new with SQLite.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM...` use `SELECT DISTINCT date FROM...`

Comment: @forpas won't this select (and copy) only the `date` column?

Comment: I mean `SELECT DISTINCT date, <other columns>`, but don't select the id.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I had to modify a bit the code, replacing `SELECT *` with `SELECT date,col1,col2` and, instead of deleting all values from `my_table` and then do `INSERT INTO`, I did `DROP TABLE my_table` and then `CREATE TABLE main.my_table AS SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: If you want to write this into an answer I will accept it. Otherwise I can do that myself

Comment: It's fine, you can post the code that you used to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice from @forpas, I solved this with the following code:

Assuming the columns to be `id`,`date`,`col1` and `col2`

```
ATTACH DATABASE secondary.db AS temp_db
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table_temp
CREATE TABLE my_table_temp AS SELECT date,col1,col2 FROM my_table
INSERT INTO main.my_table_temp SELECT date,col1,col2 FROM temp_db.my_table
DROP TABLE my_table /* I need to recreate my_table as I've removed a column*/
CREATE TABLE main.my_table AS SELECT DISTINCT date,col1,col2 FROM main.my_table_temp ORDER BY date
DROP TABLE my_table_temp
```

also, I automatized the extraction of the column names doing

```
SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('my_table');
```

This is then passed to the python code running the script and the column `id` is removed from the list. Note that the second (and following) time I run this code, the column `id` won't be present in `my_table` to start with. However this approach allows the code to be the same in the two cases: either if the column `id` is there or not.

This procedure is then iterated over each table name to fully merge the two databases.